# Where to place JQuery (set :visibility via CSS) in a BackBone View

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, backbone.js

I think this question ultimately boils down to where I should place the JQuery code, and I am unsure for backbone.js.

I have a nested div :

```
<div>Parent
  <div class='pull-right remove-measure-btn'>Child</div>
</div>
```

and I want the child to only show when the parent is being hovered.

So I can use this code (top lines within the func() in the `render()` of the parent Backbone.View.extend:

```
render: function():
....
 $(this.el).hover(
      function() {
          $('.remove-measure-btn').show();
          // $('.remove-measure-btn').css('visibility' : 'visible');
      },
      function() {
          $('.remove-measure-btn').hide();
          // $('.remove-measure-btn').css('visibility' : 'hidden');
      }
  );
....
return this;
},
```

But this only toggles the display, and since I am using Bootstrap and taking advantage of `.pull-right`, I need to toggle CSS' `:visibility`, and not `display:` to keep the height of the child div in place when it is not visible.  So if I use the second line from within the above code block, I get an undefined error, since the compiled template has been returned yet (i think....).

So where do I place the JQuery to change the CSS visibilty, or how do I change the rendering to accomodate the code where it is?

Notes:

- There are many of these "parent" and "child" divs.
- I am assuming it is best to use the selector with `this.el` to tie the interaction directly as opposed to using several global `document.ready()`s, but maybe I am not aware of a "safe/good" way to accomplish it using this method

Comment: Why you bind the event in the render? Backbone views have an events object. Why don't you use that?

Comment: Why do you need to use javascript at all for this? This can be done entirely with CSS.

Comment: @chchrist Because I am unsure of its placement.   I was unaware that bbones events handled mouseenter and mouseleave

Comment: jcsanyi's answer is both correct ,and the most simple and elegant answer to this question. There is no reason not to use his approach, despite the fact you can do it using backbone and jQuery. Overcomplicating things is a code smell.

Comment: @dcarson I'm of two minds on this: while it's true that it's probably simpler to use CSS, I think it's more idiomatic to handle events in the Backbone view itself. I know if I was looking at someone else's code I would be surprised if something other than say a color change or some other appearance modification was done in the style sheet rather than in the view.

Comment: @steveax: Your point is a valid one and you have now made me of two minds as well! This case certainly sits on the fence between styling and functionality. I agree functionality should be encapsulated within the view and I also do not like unnecessary code. However, looking at the architectural aspects of your answer has put it in a different light considering the fact that the question has a Backbone context. If Backbone was out of the picture, it would be CSS all the way for me. Considering backbone is used, I think you have a strong argument for your approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As chcrist notes, the "Backbone" way of doing this is to use the [events hash](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents):

```js
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
      'mouseenter': 'showChild',
      'mouseleave': 'hideChild'
    },

    render: function () {
      //...
    },

    showChild: function () {
      $('.remove-measure-btn').css({'visibility' : 'visible'});
    },

    hideChild: function () {
      $('.remove-measure-btn').css({'visibility' : 'hidden'});
    }

});
```

Also, I'm assuming this is a typo, but this code is wrong:

```
$('.remove-measure-btn').css('visibility' : 'hidden');
```

You can either pass an object (one or more style properties):

```
$('.remove-measure-btn').css({'visibility' : 'hidden'});
```

Or pass one property/value pair:

```
$('.remove-measure-btn').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

Comment: Why use javascript at all?

Comment: @jcsanyi sure, in this particular case, your CSS solution will work, but it may not in other situations and the idiomatic way to handle events in Backbone views is the event hash.

Comment: But the question isn't about how to handle events - it's about how to set the visibility based on hover. For this question, the best answer is to use CSS.

Comment: @steveax thanks for catching the typo.   I had just learned about the two options before writing this code anyway, and I think by the time i read the API, and wrote the code, I mixed the code.  Being newer to JS, it also didn't catch my attention for the lack of the curly braces to send the object!

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with straight CSS. Javascript (backbone or otherwise) is not required.

Adding the following CSS to your page will get you exactly what you need without the use of javascript:

```
.remove-measure-btn {
    visibility:hidden;
}
div:hover > .remove-measure-btn {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

A fiddle showing this in action is here: http://jsfiddle.net/35TXY/

Comment: I agree this should not be voted down. (I voted it back up). Its true that there are two ways to do this. It's also true that CSS cannot be used for as many purposes as JavaScript. However in this case, this approach 100% answers the question and is the most efficient and elegant solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

try `$('remove-measure-button').addClass('hidden')` and `removeClass('hidden')`. Define hidden:

```
.hidden {visibility: hidden;}
```

Comment: Why use javascript at all?

Comment: @jcsanyi because javascripts doesn't limit you to modifying only style properties.

Comment: But the question was about how to set the visibility - which is a style property. The correct answer to that question is to use CSS.